# Cannot access Linq when using Razor without MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

Has anyone had experience with Razor without MVC. I am using a Template engine build up from http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=208 but I cannot use any of the linq queries within the Razor code for example

```
<div>
    @Model.Person.First().Firstname
</div>
```

This throws the error:

> System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition
>   for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

For this example `Model` contains a List of `Person` below

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I assume you did try `@using System.Linq` ?

Comment: Yes, I have debugged and checked that the assembley was added

Comment: the syntax is wrong, `Model` is the list, so `First` needs to be called on `Model`.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: As a side note to your addition: If you use Linq in more of your views than it is easier to put it in the Web.Config file under `<system.web><compilation><assemblies><add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>` Don't forget to restart Visual Studio :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model is the list, so you need to `First` on the model not `Person`, `First` returns an instance of the `Person` class:

```
<div>
    @Model.First().Firstname
</div>
```

You need to :

- add `@using System.Data.Linq` at the top of your view
- or if you need it on all views add `<add namespace="System.Data.Linq" />` to the web.config in your Views folder.

Here is how you do it:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Data.Linq" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: I have updated the question to say that 'Model' contains a List of 'Person'. There is a far deeper issue than this. Thanks though.

Comment: Don't forget to restart Visual Studio for Intellisense support on Linq.

Comment: There is no Views folder, this is a "Class library" project and the html markup comes from the DB, please check the [link](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=208) for an example project

Comment: So put the section I provided into the app.config of the application that is actually running this code OR put it on top of the view

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did try this before my last comment with no luck.

Comment: Please note that this answer is from 2012 and refers to an early version of Razor